# macOS - [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:]

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, foundation

How can I create an instance of `NSValue` that contains a `CGAffineTransform`?

UIKit provides `[NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:]`, but AppKit does not.

Do I need to use the `valueWithBytes:objCType:` static method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGAffineTransform is a `struct`

```
struct CGAffineTransform {
  CGFloat a, b, c, d;
  CGFloat tx, ty;
};
```

The correct way how to handle structs is mentioned in [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide - Representing Non-Object Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/DataTypes.html) (Wrapping and Unwrapping Structures)

```
CGAffineTransform transform;
NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&transform objCType:@encode(CGAffineTransform)];
```